# PHP add / separators between chunks of breadcrumbs

Tags: php, slice

I have the following code which generates breadcrumbs:

```
<?php
$output = array();
$chunks = explode('/', $breadcrumbs);
foreach ($chunks as $i => $chunk) {
$output[] = sprintf(
'<a href="index.php?bc=%s">%s</a>',
implode(array_slice($chunks, 0, $i + 1)),
$chunk
);
}

echo implode(' &gt;&gt; ', $output);?>
```

Right now the $breadcrumbs that are passed through URL are lacking the proper '/' separator between file paths, and I get this: index.php?bc=historymastersdocuments

instead of this: index.php?bc=history/masters/documents/ (which is what I want to see)
so my question is how do I append a '/' between my chunks after exploding them and the breadcrumb links should be like this for each chunk

index.php?bc=history -> index.php?bc=history/masters/ -> index.php?bc=history/masters/documents/

Comment: like re-implode them with `/`!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide the glue '/' in your implode call

```
<?php
$output = array();
$chunks = explode('/', $breadcrumbs);
foreach ($chunks as $i => $chunk) {
    $output[] = sprintf('<a href="index.php?bc=%s">%s</a>', 
                        implode('/', array_slice($chunks, 0, $i + 1)),
                        $chunk);
}

echo implode(' &gt;&gt; ', $output);?>
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but that doesn't really do anything for me, I need to show the breadcrumbs as history -> history/masters/ -> history/masters/documents/ instead of just the current path in the chunk

Comment: You were just missing the 'glue' slash in your implode call